# How use click event after xhr load without query

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

When a div is clicked, it pulls in html from another webpage using AJAX. But how do I have divs on the new page clickable without using inline js.

First Page:

```
<div id='clickToLoad'>Click Here</div>
<br />
<div id='localContentHere'></div>


<script>

document.getElementById('clickToLoad').onclick = function () {

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'ajax/content.html', true);
    xhr.responseType = 'text';
    xhr.onload = function(e) {
      if (this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById('localContentHere').innerHTML = this.response;
        }
    };
    xhr.send(); 
}

document.getElementById('loadMoreContent').onclick = function () {

    alert('This is some more content');

}

</script>
```

ajax/content.html:

```
This is Some content
<br /><br />

<div id='loadMoreContent'>Load Even More Content</div>
```

I understand that the div isn't present on the page when the JS is loaded and therefor doesn't realise that that div should now have a click event. I can obviously add an inline onclick or use jQuery, but I don't want to do either of those.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can delegate just like jQuery does

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var el = event.target;
    do {
        if (el.id === 'loadMoreContent') {

            alert('This is some more content');

        }
    } while (el = el.parentNode);
}, false);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/J4ZL2/)